# Ban discord v13 send dm

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

Good evening I made my bot in v13 but I can't manage to make my bot send a message in dm before banning the person I want but without success so I come to ask for help here is the code if you want. :

```
const discord = module.require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "ban",
  category: "moderation",
  description: "Ban anyone with one shot whithout knowing anyone xD",
  usage: "ban <@user> <reason>",
  userPerms: ["BAN_MEMBERS"],
  botPerms: ["EMBED_LINKS", "BAN_MEMBERS"],
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
    if (!reason) reason = "Unspecified";

    const target = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.users.cache.get(args[0]);

    if (!target) {
      return message.channel.send(
        `**${message.author.username}**, Please mention the person who you want to ban.`
      );
    }

    if (target.id === message.author.id) {
      return message.channel.send(
        `**${message.author.username}**, You can not ban yourself!`
      );
    }
    if (target.id === message.guild.ownerId) {
      return message.channel.send("You cannot Ban The Server Owner");
    }

    let embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("Action : Ban")
      .setDescription(`Banned ${target} (${target.id})\nReason: ${reason}`)
      .setColor("#ff2050")
      .setThumbnail(target.avatarURL)
      .setFooter(`Banned by ${message.author.tag}`);

    await message.guild.bans.create(target, {
      reason: reason
    }).then(() => {
        message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
      });
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the bot does not have permission to ban the member you're trying to ban, therefore the `.then` callback not being called.

Either use a `.catch()` callback in the promise or put the method in a `try{}catch{}` block.

Using `.catch()`

```js
await message.guild.bans.create(target, {
    reason: reason
})
.catch((e) => {
    console.log(`Error: ${e}`);
})
.then(() => {
    message.channel.send({
        embeds: [embed]
    })
})
```

Using try/catch:

```js
try {
    await message.guild.bans.create(target, { reason: reason})
    .then(() => {
        message.channel.send({
            embeds: [embed]
        })
    })
}
catch (e) {
    console.log(`Error: ${e}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the bot needs to DM a user, the user needs to be in that guild, so you need to send the DM them run the ban event, also in order to avoid crash use try/catch method

```
try {
    member.send({embeds: [coolembed]})
    
catch (e) {
    message.channel.send({content: 'I cannot DM this user'})
    console.log(`Error: ${e}`);
}
await message.guild.bans.create(target, {
      reason: reason
    })
```